# How to pass props from React Router 4 to a Container?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm working to pass a prop from my router to my layout file but the prop `customClass` is not being passed.

Here is my React app's router:

```
const WithMainLayout = ({component: Component, ...more}) => {
  return <Route {...more} render={props => {
    return (
      <MainLayout {...props}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </MainLayout>
    );
  }}/>;
};

const App = ({store}) => {
  return (
    <StoreProvider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <ScrollToTop>
          <Switch>
            <WithMainLayout exact path="/" component={Home2} customClass="XXX" />
          </Switch>
        </ScrollToTop>
      </ConnectedRouter>
    </StoreProvider>
  );
};
```

**the problem**
In MainLayout, I'm not getting the customClass prop:

```
class MainLayout extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.customClass);
  ...
```

This is being logged as `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the `props` argument passed from router to the render method callback does not contain the properties you applied to `<WithMainLaout />`, it contains history, location, and match. To fix your issue you can do the following:

```
const WithMainLayout = ({component: Component, ...more}) => {
  return <Route {...more} render={props => {
    return (
      <MainLayout {...props} {...more}>
        <Component {...props} {...more} />
      </MainLayout>
    );
  }}/>;
};
```

This will give you the properties from both.

Answer (score 0):

Pass props down like this:

```
<WithMainLayout exact path="/" component={<Home2 customClass={"XXX"} />} />
```

Comment: Sorry. What's that?